# I have an area light at 200 w and as you can see the light is too soft ,is it normal ? (render is also not strong enough )

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have an area light at 200 w and as you can see the light is too soft ,is it normal ? (render is also not strong enough ).[image]

Comment: Hello, 200w should be enough, could you please share your file (remove the parts that you don't want to share)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It says the file its too big ,im sorry its me first time using it i don't know how it really works all this.

Comment: you can use another platform like workupload, and share the link

Comment: is we Transfer ok ?

Comment: sure, use wetransfer, copy paste the link

Comment: https://we.tl/t-wHpWQxI0Vm

Comment: there's a setting that makes the whole scene darker than it should be, you can append all your objects in a new file but it would be interesting to find what is the bad setting...

Comment: Ok, i will do that thank you very much. :D